# How to create Scald Atoms media library for each content type?

Tags: nodes, views, scald

I need to categorize the "Atoms Library" items in a way that there would be a "Atoms Library" for each content type. How  could create a Atoms Library for each conten type? or How I could categorize the items in "Atoms Library" according to content type?

Is this possible to create a "Atoms Library" for each content type?

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/project/scald

Answer (score 1):

There are two Views that come with Scald:

- scald_library - Which, for our purposes, is what controls the format of the menu in the editor.
- scald_atoms - Which controls the format of the Scald Library at /admin/content/atoms.

Both are fully editable views.

For the admin page, clone the View and assign each one a unique filter for Atom:Type and give each View a unique path URL. Add these URLs to an admin menu somewhere to make them findable.

The editing menu is a little more complicated. Cloning and filtering the View is the same, but I believe using them would require adding new functionality to either the editor or Scald. Though people editing content can still filter by type in the Scald search pane.